# PayPal item_name passed to IPN and PDP as “Shopping Cart”

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, shopping-cart, paypal-pdt

From around 10th August ‘17 my IPN and PDT PHP programs are now both passed an `item_name` of `Shopping Cart` intermittently (perhaps one in ten transactions) even though the item name is hardcoded in my 'PayPal Standard HTML' interface (i.e. the user isn't given any opportunity to set it). This uses a simple

```
input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"
```

so has no reason think that is in a shopping cart call or to rename the item.

My guess is that HTML API's `cmd=_xclick` (i.e. BuyNow) is, at some point in Paypal's own processing, being handled as a `cmd=_cart` and `item_name` is being treated as unset (and PayPal is then defaulting it to "`Shopping Cart`").

When I do a downloaded activity report, the following fields are blank on the offending items: `Item title`, `Item ID`,    `Quantity`

The payments were processed (credited to us) successfully but the resulting bad IPN made the order undeliverable: we had no idea what the customer ordered!

Comment: There are other reports of this. You need to open a support ticket with PayPal, although I'm sure they know about it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved at PayPal end. Going forward, you will get the correct item name from PayPal.

Comment: If we resend our IPNs will they now be sent correctly?

Comment: The fix has been pushed for incoming payments. The internal teams are working for correcting the impacted transactions. Please file a ticket to PayPal MTS at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/ for further updates.